# SpringBoot web services multiple data sources only one working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have developed two webservices using Spring Boot framework and I have them in the same project. Each webservice use a different DB, say ws1 uses Oracle1 and ws2 uses Oracle2. I have defined a DataBaseConfig with the beans definition but when I run the app, always works one webservice ( and it's always the same ).

DataBaseConfig

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {
@Bean(name = "ora1")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource") 
public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();}

@Bean(name = "ora2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource") 
public DataSource sqliteDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();}

 @Bean(name = "clients")
    @Autowired
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Qualifier("datasource")
    public JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate(DataSource datasource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource); }

    @Bean(name = "places")
    @Autowired
     @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
     @Qualifier("secondDatasource")
    public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(DataSource secondDatasource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondDatasource);} 
}
```

I have the services definition with the sql statements and the definition

```
@Service
public class ClientsService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("clients") 
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

and the other service

```
@Service
public class PlacesService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("places") 
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Then in each controller I have de mapping @RequestMapping. When I run the app I have no connection-related errors and if I separate the webservices in 2 projects, each works fine.

Comment: Instead of `@Qualifier("datasource")` and `@Qualifier("secondDatasource")` it should be `@Qualifier("ora1")` and `@Qualifier("ora2")`, should not it?

Comment: I've tried that but still isn't working. The ws that works is not the one set as 'Primary'. The error I get for the webservice 'clients' is ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, but the query is working ( I have also the webservices in separate projects working correctly )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going wrong here, including some unnecessary annotations. See below, note the location of @Qualifier and the qualifier name:

```
@Bean(name = "clients")
public JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ora1") DataSource datasource) {
     return new JdbcTemplate(datasource); 
}

@Bean(name = "places")
@Primary
public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ora2") DataSource secondDatasource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(secondDatasource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resolving by bean name, which is a bad idea IMO because it's not typesafe, why don't you use constructor injection and create the services in the configuration class (ditch `@Service` annotation). Create the `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` beans as usual, don't give them any names (the default is the method name), and also create `new PlacesService(placesJdbcTemplate())`. The result is a lot simpler code.

This is assuming you want both databases active at runtime. If not, use `@Profile`.