# Spring 4 with 2 jdbc connections

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-4

How do I configure 2 jdbc connections using Spring4 java config classes ?

Should 2 transaction managers be configure for those two connections ?

Thx

Edit:

I'm want to use just JdbcTemplate no JPA, Spring Data.

Comment: 1. The same way you define one, but by doing it twice. 2. It depends. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need 2 datasources? What are they used for? Should updates made in the two databases be done in a single, atomic transaction?

Comment: I have 2 datasources that I have to access. Each database should have a seperate transaction created. Where Can I find a good example ? pls don't say google, i've tried :)

Comment: Define two datasources, each with a different name. Define two TransactionManagers, each with a different name, and each using their datasource. When using `@Transactional`, specify the name of the transaction manager to use. When injecting a DataSource, use the Qualifier annotation to specify which one to inject. Your question is too broad. Read the documentation, try something, and if you have a concrete problem, post it, with the relevant code.

Comment: That said, using google gives back plenty of examples, including official examples from Spring: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Comment: Thank you very much :) I forgot to mention that I want to use just JdbcTemplate, no JPA and Spring Data.

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973743/springboot-web-services-multiple-data-sources-only-one-working), and my answer for a better design than the OP chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example configuration might looks something like the following. I also pushed a full sample to GitHub which can be found [here](https://github.com/seancarroll/stackoverflow-44985183)

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager firstDataSourceTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(firstDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Primary
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate firstJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(firstDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondDataSourceTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(secondDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate secondJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondDataSource());
    }

}
```